# Analytic expression for implicit function

Tags: polynomials, optimization, problem-solving, parametric

I have a function defined as

```
f[k_]:= Maximize[{(x^2/(1+x^2))((1-x^(2k))/(1+x^(2k+1)))^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

I would like to find an analytic form of $f$ as a function of $k$.

Differentiating the argument of the Maximize in $f$ with respect to $x$, I obtain the condition:

```
1+x^(3+4k) - x^(2k)(1+x)(x^2(1+2k)- x + (1+2k)) == 0
```

Is there a way to get the analytic form of $f$ as a function of $k$ alone?

Answer (score 1):

Suprisingly, [Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.net) does find an explicit formula for the zeros of that polynomial. The expressions are truly scary, however... and you'd need to check if your solutions are at the ends of the interval, not where the derivative is zero (at first glance, the solutions seem to be complex, not real).

What do you need the expressions for? Perhaps a numerical solution of the resulting equation is more practical.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if you can give me the explicit formula for the zeros. I am interested in the real solution with 0 <= x <= 1. I have a numerical answer but would like to understand at least the leading orders of the behaviour of $f$ as a function of $k$.

Comment: @monkas, get some computer algebra system to give them. The mentioned Maxima is free and not so hard to use, or go for Wolfram's free web version. With Maxima at least you can then expand the solution in series in $k$, or torture it in other ways. The expressions are several screenfuls...